# Is there any place where defaultChecked is more advantageous than just referencing checked?

Tags: javascript

What use-case would `defaultChecked` be better suited than `checked`?

> **checked** — *Boolean*
>   Returns / Sets the current state of the element when type is checkbox or radio.
>
> **defaultChecked** — *Boolean*
> Returns / Sets the default state of a radio button or checkbox as originally specified in HTML that created this object.

Source: [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

```js
document.getElementById('opt2').checked = true;
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => console.log(input.checked))
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked id="opt1"> <!-- defaultChecked -->
<input type="checkbox" id="opt2"> <!-- checked by user or js -->
```

Comment: `defaultChecked` is whether it's checked *by default*, `checked` whether it's *currently* checked. Which to use depends which you want, but combining them like that doesn't seem likely to be correct.

Comment: Suppose I've never seen a use-case where initially set vs currently set mattered, maybe if you're comparing values on save e.g. `(selector.checked && (selector.defaultChecked !== selector.checked))`. Thanks.

Comment: If you'd stop a for a minute and think about this line `as originally specified in HTML that created this object.`

Comment: They have completely different behavior. ```checked``` is to show option that was checked by user in form for edit something, ```defaultChecked``` - just to push user leave the option checked in a new form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the form can be reset by `<input type="reset">` or something calling `.reset()`, `defaultChecked` would allow you to dynamically change the meaning and behavior of resetting the form.

Another possible use-case where `defaultChecked` may be beneficial is making an element included in or excluded from a selection with [`:default`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:default) pseudo-class. Maybe this can be used for styling purposes.

However, as the previous comments stated, both properties have different behavior and I think it is important to consider the semantic implications of changing the "default" of something and choose accordingly.

```js
document.getElementById('opt2').checked = true;
document.getElementById('opt3').defaultChecked = true;

document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(input => console.log(input.checked));
document.querySelectorAll('input:default').forEach(input => console.log(input.id));
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" checked id="opt1"> <!-- defaultChecked -->
    <input type="checkbox" id="opt2"> <!-- checked by user or js -->
    <input type="checkbox" id="opt3"> <!-- defaultChecked by js -->
    <input type="reset">
</form>
```